# Admin pages and posts layout messed up

Tags: wordpress, layout, admin

I've got an error in my WordPress installation.
The error is that the columns in the wp admin pages and posts are messed up.

See image here:

[image: screenshot]

I've updated to the latest release of wordpress, tried to disable all plugins and tried to change the column number. Nothing fixed it.

Has anybody seen the same issue and/or know a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching theme? weird problem..
You also try to download wordpress and replacing all css files in `wp-admin/css` with the newly downloaded.
If that doesn't work replace the `wp-admin/js`.

If that doesn't work replace the whole `wp-admin` folder.

Finally you could try to 'reinstall WordPress' from the dashboard -> updates screen.

Make sure you use the same versions of WP.
And as always make a backup before you start.

Comment: Hi janw, yay.. i replaced the js folder and it made my day! Thanks! :)